# ERROR in SQL syntax near Integer data type while creating a table, don't know why it's failing

Tags: mysql-5.6

```
CREATE TABLE ProfileMiningStats(server VARCHAR(20), DateStatsCollected DATE(), NoSubmittedCompanies INT, NoCompaniesFinishedSuccessfully INT, AvgTimeTakenByEachProfile TIME());
```

seeing the below ERROR Message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(), NoSubmittedCompanies INT, NoCompaniesFinishedSuccessfully INT, AvgTimeTakenB' at line 1
```

Please correct the query if its wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
create table ProfileMiningStats(
  server VARCHAR(20), 
  DateStatsCollected DATE, 
  NoSubmittedCompanies INT, 
  NoCompaniesFinishedSuccessfully INT, 
  AvgTimeTakenByEachProfile TIME);
```

You had () after the DATE and the TIME datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it will work. (You have used functions like Date(), Time() that is the problem)
    create table ProfileMiningStats(
    server VARCHAR(20), 
    DateStatsCollected DATE, NoSubmittedCompanies INT,
    NoCompaniesFinishedSuccessfully INT, 
    AvgTimeTakenByEachProfile TIME
    );